# How to take multiple strings from inputs and place them into the same array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, input

How can I take a string from each input field and place them in the same array?

The code I have currently is this..

```js
var input1 = document.querySelector('.form');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var array = [];

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){

  array.push(input.value);
  
  console.log(array);


});
```

```html
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      <input type="text" class="form">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      <input type="text" class="form">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary text-center" id="btn">SUBMIT</button>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `console.log(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input')));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.from` to select all `.form`s with `querySelectorAll`, and pass a mapping function that extracts the `.value` from each:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.form');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  const arr = Array.from(inputs, elm => elm.value);
  console.log(arr);
});
```

```html
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      <input type="text" class="form">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      <input type="text" class="form">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary text-center" id="btn">SUBMIT</button>
```